# Attempt to Load-Update-Resave Argument in a game

Tags: python, python-3.x, save

I am very new to programing and trying to learn by doing creating a text adventure game and reading Python documentation/blogs.

My issue is I'm attempting to save/load data in a text game to create some elements which carry over from game to game and are passed as arguments.  Specifically with this example my goal recall, update and load an incrementing iteration each time the game is played past the intro.  Specially my intention here is to import the saved march_iteration number, display it to the user as a default name suggestion, then iterate the iteration number and save the updated saved march_iteration number.

From my attempts at debugging this I seem to be updating the value and saving the updated value of 2 to the game.sav file correctly, so I believe my issues is either I'm failing to load the data properly or overwriting the saved value with the static one somehow.  I've read as much documentation as I can find but from the articles I've read on saving and loading to json I cannot identify where my code is wrong.

Below is a small code snippet I wrote just to try and get the save/load working.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
import json

def _save(dummy):
    f = open("game.sav", 'w+')
    json.dump(world_states, f)
    f.close

def _continue(dummy):
    f = open("game.sav", 'r+')
    world_states = json.load(f)
    f.close

world_states = {
    "march_iteration" : 1
}

def _resume():
    _continue("")
_resume()
print ("world_states['march_iteration']", world_states['march_iteration'])

current_iteration = world_states["march_iteration"]

def name_the_march(curent_iteration=world_states["march_iteration"]):
    march_name = input("\nWhat is the name of your march?  We suggest TrinMar#{}. >".format(current_iteration))
    if len(march_name) == 0:
        print("\nThe undifferentiated units shift nerviously, unnerved and confused, perhaps even angry.")
        print("\nPlease give us a proper name executor.  The march must not be nameless, that would be chaos.")
        name_the_march()
    else:
        print("\nThank you Executor.  The {} march begins its long journey.".format(march_name))
        world_states['march_iteration'] = (world_states['march_iteration'] +1)
        print ("world_states['march_iteration']", world_states['march_iteration'])
#Line above used only for debugging purposed
        _save("")
name_the_march()
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution which works for my purposes allowing me to load, update and resave.  It isn't the most efficient but it works, the prints are just there to display the number being properly loaded and updated before being resaved.

Pre-requisite:  This example assumes you've already created a file for this to open.

```
import json

#Initial data
iteration = 1

#Restore from previously saved from a file
with open('filelocation/filename.json') as f:
  iteration = json.load(f)
print(iteration)

iteration = iteration + 1
print(iteration)

#save updated data
f = open("filename.json", 'w')
json.dump(iteration, f)
f.close
```